# Wordpress the_post() break duplicate posts

Tags: wordpress

I have array with duplicated post ids

```
array = [71, 82, 71, 86, 82]
```

If I will do simple wordpress loop like

```
while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
```

I will see posts with 71, 82, 86 ids
How it possible to show all posts with ids in array array = [71, 82, 71, 86, 82]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop for repeated id.

```
$ids=Array(71, 82, 71, 86, 82);

global $post;
foreach ($ids as $id) :
    $post = get_post($id);
    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title();
endforeach;
```

It simply get id from array and get post from database as per id.

You can find more details here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/

Comment: It is not true, you don't test you code. No reason the_post and get_post. Please test before answer.

Comment: why? may i know?

Comment: you can get post by id using this method

Comment: Because you copy this code from wordpress.stackexchange